# Error parsing JSON if it contains an array

Tags: json, swift

I am parsing a URL which is returning data in array format as below:

```
[
{"_id":"5bb8b6038fb09210e09fd5c6","name":"John","city":"Dallas","country":"USA","__v":0},{"_id":"5bb8b6258fb09210e09fd5c7","name":"Robert","city":"SFO","country":"USA","__v":0}
]
```

I have written model class as below:

```
class Peoples: Codable{
    let peoples:[People]
    init(peoples:[People]) {
        self.peoples = peoples
    }
}

class People: Codable{
    var _id : String
    var name : String
    var city : String
    var country : String
    var __v : Int

    init(
        _id : String,
        name : String,
        city : String,
        country : String,
        __v : Int
    )
    {
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
        self.country = country
        self.__v = __v

    }
}
```

And I am parsing JSON data using JSONDecoder.

```
class HomeTabController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    private var varPeoples= [People]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = URL(string: “<SomeURL>“)else {return}
        guard  let downloadURL = url else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil
               else
               {
                print( "Something is wrong in URL")
                return;
               }
            print(data)
            do{
                let pplList=  JSONDecoder().decode(Peoples.self, from: data). // This line is giving data incorrect format error.
                self.varPeoples = pplList.peoples

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch{
                print( error.localizedDescription)
            }
     }
}
```

If the JSON data does not have an array[] I am able to parse it. But my URL is returning data with array [] symbol. So can any one please fix the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json you have is an array of `People`, not `Peoples`:

```
do {
    let pplList =  try JSONDecoder().decode([People].self, from: data) // This line is giving data incorrect format error.
    print("pplList =", pplList)
} catch {
    print( error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because if the root object is an array implementing an umbrella struct will break the decoding process.

Just decode the array.

Some general *`Decoding`* notes:

- If the JSON is read-only in most cases a `struct` is sufficient.
- If the JSON is read-only conforming to `Decodable` is sufficient.
- If the JSON is read-only declare the struct members as constants (`let`).
- It's highly recommended to add `CodingKeys` to transform *weird* keys to (more descriptive) names conforming to the Swift naming convention.
- You don't have to write an initializer even if the object is a class, `Decodable` provides one.
- To avoid *singular-plural* confusion name a `struct` in singular form (`Person`) and the array in plural form (`people`). Semantically each object in `people` represents one `Person`.
- **Never** print `error.localizedDescription` when catching a `Decoding` error. `localizedDescription` returns a generic string but not the actual error description. Print always the entire `error` instance.

---

```
struct Person: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case id = "_id", name, city, country, somethingMoreDescriptiveThan__v = "__v"}

    let id : String
    let name : String
    let city : String
    let country : String
    let somethingMoreDescriptiveThan__v : Int
}

...

private var people = [Person]()

...

do {
   self.people = JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data)
   DispatchQueue.main.async{
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```